# WSO2 BPS 3.2 human task assignment to multiple people creating Process in failed status

Tags: wso2, bpel

I am trying to create wso2 human task where the approval has to be given by multiple owners in some sequence. I am calling human task from Asynchronous BPEL process. I am able to upload the Process and task packages successfully. But when I try to create the process instance, i am getting below error in the logs:

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.integration.AxisHumanTaskMessageReceiver} -  Task creation failed.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.openjpa.model.provider.OrganizationalEntityProviderFactory.getOrganizationalEntityProvider(OrganizationalEntityProviderFactory.java:26)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.openjpa.JPATaskUtil.processGenericHumanRoles(JPATaskUtil.java:70)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.openjpa.HumanTaskDAOConnectionImpl.createTask(HumanTaskDAOConnectionImpl.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskEngine.createTask(HumanTaskEngine.java:81)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskEngine.access$000(HumanTaskEngine.java:38)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskEngine$1.call(HumanTaskEngine.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskEngine$1.call(HumanTaskEngine.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:880)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskEngine.invoke(HumanTaskEngine.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.integration.AxisHumanTaskMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AxisHumanTaskMessageReceiver.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2014-02-07 12:33:32,878]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.b4p.extension.PeopleActivity} -  SOAP Fault: urn:approveurn:uuid:1153d791-6283-4621-8b37-0e3a5095169esoapenv:Server

Code snippet for setting the workflow in Task is given below.

`<htd:peopleAssignments>
                <htd:potentialOwners>
                    <htd:sequence type="all">
                        <htd:from logicalPeopleGroup="shippingLine">
                            <htd:argument name="role">
                                shippingLineRole
                            </htd:argument>
                        </htd:from>
                        <htd:from logicalPeopleGroup="cho">
                            <htd:argument name="role">
                                choRole
                            </htd:argument>
                        </htd:from>
                    </htd:sequence>
                </htd:potentialOwners>

`

Any idea what is going wrong here. As the task creation is working fine when workflow has single owner.

Answer (score 0):

Your people assignment is wrong for multiple users. From BPS 3.1.0 WSO2 BPS supports Expression and literal based user assignment. If you need multiple user assignments you need to use either expression based or literal based user assignment. See humantask spec [1] for correct syntax.

[1] http://docs.oasis-open.org/bpel4people/ws-humantask-1.1-spec-cs-01.html#_Ref193111939

Comment: After following your advice, I am able to create the task. But my requirement is that when USER1 approves the task, it should be assigned to next user say USER2 in the workflow. Currently as soon as user USER1 approves the task, process moves to COMPLETED status while it should wait for the next user's approval in the workflow. Can you please point me to some example which shows the configuration for the same. I tried it with htd:sequence element but it is not working as expected.

Comment: In current implementation of the BPS 3.2.0 Routing Patterns are not supported.

Comment: Thanks Hashitha! Is it expected in some near future version? Also we want to create custom UI for our approval workflow. I was trying to generate the client code from HumanTaskClientAPIAdmin wsdl but it is failing. I followed Nandika's blog on the same topic. In that blog, there is a link [http://people.wso2.com/~nandika/htwsdl/](http://people.wso2.com/~nandika/htwsdl/) to download the correct wsdls but it is not working. Can you please suggest from where we can download correct wsdls for all admin services of BPS.

Comment: I am not sure the timeline when it is available. But you can achieve this functionality using, BPEL + HumanTask scenario using multiple tasks. You don't need to generate stubs, it is available with BPS pack. You can find the org.wso2.carbon.humantask.stub jar under <BPS_HOME>/repository/component/plugins/. In case of you need the wsdl, this is the url to wsdl. http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/business-processes/humantask/org.wso2.carbon.humantask/4.2.2/src/main/resources/META-INF/HumanTaskClientAPIAdmin.wsdl