# WSO2 BPS 3.2 human task assignment to multiple people Via expressions e.g., by retrieving data from the input message of the human task

Tags: wso2, bpel

I have create wso2 human task where the approval has to be given by multiple owners in parallely. I am calling human task from Synchronous BPEL process. I am able to upload the Process and task packages successfully. But only one potential owner get approval not others.This link said BPS 3.2.0 Routing Patterns are not supported.[WSO2 BPS 3.2 human task assignment to multiple people creating Process in failed status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621847/wso2-bps-3-2-human-task-assignment-to-multiple-people-creating-process-in-failed)

So I put this this in my code.

```
 <htd:potentialOwners>                         <htd:from>htd:getInput("ClaimApprovalRequest")/test10:UserList/test10:ME</htd:from>
</htd:potentialOwners>
<htd:potentialOwners>                          <htd:from>htd:getInput("ClaimApprovalRequest")/test10:UserList/test10:HBR</htd:from>
</htd:potentialOwners>
```

''

Any idea what is going wrong here. As the task creation is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what you are doing now: when you assign to potentialOwners, that means that any one of the people in that group can complete the task. That is not the same as: all people have to carry out the task.

What you probably want, is:

```
<htd:potentialOwners><htd:parallel type="all">...owners...</htd:parallel><htd:potentialOwners>
```

I do not know if WSO2 supports that though.